# How to apply color palette to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, color-palette

I have numerical arrays i would like to plot on user interface.

I already use canvas to plot them in grey using same color code for all rgb channels. 
I would like to know if it exists a function to apply color palette as there is with python and his colormap parameter for example or have i to do it by myself ?

a plot in grey  here

`$`  https://jsfiddle.net/30pn5nfw/

how to do to apply color code from blue (for min value) to red (max value ) passing by white ( mean value ) for heat representation of data

or going from maroon , then green ,then blue, to  white for relief representation

best regards
Tinnitus

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking - post some code

Comment: The function exists (assuming your task is computable) although it may be your task to arrive at that function.

Comment: In javascript canvas, you do not have a color palette. You can only manipulate the rgba-value of a pixel.

Comment: ok i added an example and explanations

Comment: Mccainz can you developp a bit more ?

Comment: If it doesn't exit with canvas is there an other way to plot 2D array quickly ,  not using highchart or similar cause it needs 3times too much data for a basic  2D ( image ) représentation  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did it myself,  just astonished that there is no library still existing to do kind of thing , i have often have feeling to reinvent the wheel with JS, it is not a so young language

Comment: Hi @froggy, I'm trying to do the same thing.  Would you please share the blue to red colormap array that you used?

Comment: ...or tell us how you created your own?